# How to refresh list of the navigation drawer as soon as its open/closed in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I have created navigation drawer and displaying items in list. My list is static but i am displaying points. So when users select the items in the list and do some activity he get the points. So i want to update the points as soon as he gets. How can i do this./

Below is my code:

**Activity Class:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_page);
    // Initializing
    dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constant.LOGIN_CHECK,
            Constant.PRIVATE_MODE);
    editSharedPreferences = sharedPreferences.edit();
    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constant.IS_ALREADY_LOGIN,
            false)) {
        loginInBackground();
    }
    String p1 = sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.USERS_POINTS,
            "");
    String p2 = sharedPreferences.getString(
            Constant.LEVEL_ONE_POINTS, "");
    String p3 = sharedPreferences.getString(
            Constant.LEVEL_TWO_POINTS, "");

    String pointText = " POINTS";
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("OVERVIEW", R.drawable.ic_action_eye,
            Color.DKGRAY, Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("EARN POINTS", R.drawable.ic_action_dollor,
            Color.GREEN, Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("MY POINTS ", p1 + pointText, Color.BLACK,
            Color.BLACK));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("REFERRALS POINTS LV1 ", p2 + pointText,
            Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("REFERRALS POINTS LV2 ", p3 + pointText,
            Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("WITHDRAW REWARDS",
            R.drawable.ic_action_home, Color.DKGRAY, Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("MY PROFILE", R.drawable.ic_action_settings,
            Color.DKGRAY, Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("HELP", R.drawable.help_d, Color.DKGRAY,
            Color.TRANSPARENT));

    adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
            dataList);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        SelectItem(0);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    String pointsLeft = sharedPreferences.getString(
            Constant.POINTS_LEFT, "");
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    MenuItem pointsMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    pointsMenu.setTitle(pointsLeft + " Points");
    return true;
}

public void SelectItem(int possition) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    switch (possition) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new FragmentWelcome();
        args.putString(FragmentWelcome.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                .getItemName());
        args.putInt(FragmentWelcome.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID,
                dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager0 = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager0.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FragmentAppList();
        args.putString(FragmentWelcome.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                .getItemName());
        args.putInt(FragmentWelcome.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID,
                dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager1 = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager1.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new FragmentRedeemPoints();
        args.putString(FragmentWelcome.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                .getItemName());
        args.putInt(FragmentWelcome.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID,
                dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager2 = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager2.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        args.putString(FragmentWelcome.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                .getItemName());
        args.putInt(FragmentWelcome.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID,
                dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager6 = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager6.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new HelpFragment();
        args.putString(FragmentWelcome.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                .getItemName());
        args.putInt(FragmentWelcome.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID,
                dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager7 = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager7.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        break;

    default:

        break;
    }

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        SelectItem(position);

    }
}
```

**CustomDrawerAdapter:**

```
public class CustomDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerItem> {

Context context;
List<DrawerItem> drawerItemList;
int layoutResID;

public CustomDrawerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID,
        List<DrawerItem> listItems) {
    super(context, layoutResourceID, listItems);
    this.context = context;
    this.drawerItemList = listItems;
    this.layoutResID = layoutResourceID;

}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    DrawerItemHolder drawerHolder;
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        drawerHolder = new DrawerItemHolder();

        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
        drawerHolder.ItemName = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.drawer_itemName);
        drawerHolder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon);
        drawerHolder.pointsText = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.get_login);
        drawerHolder.divider = view.findViewById(R.id.dividerView);
        drawerHolder.itemLayoutColor = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.itemLayoutColor);
        view.setTag(drawerHolder);

    } else {
        drawerHolder = (DrawerItemHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    DrawerItem dItem = (DrawerItem) this.drawerItemList.get(position);
    if (dItem.getPointText() == null) {
        drawerHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(
                dItem.getImgResID()));
        drawerHolder.pointsText.setVisibility(view.GONE);
    } else {
        drawerHolder.pointsText.setText(dItem.getPointText());
        }
    drawerHolder.itemLayoutColor.setBackgroundColor(dItem.layoutColorCode);
    drawerHolder.divider.setBackgroundColor(dItem.colorCode);
    drawerHolder.ItemName.setText(dItem.getItemName());

    return view;
}

private static class DrawerItemHolder {
    TextView ItemName;
    ImageView icon;
    TextView pointsText;
    View divider;
    LinearLayout itemLayoutColor;
}
 }
```

Comment: you want to refresh the navigation drawer list as soon as it opens or closed??

Comment: @user3154663 yeah this is what i want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally i have fixed this by using below code. I want to answer to this so that  others can get the reference from this. @user3154663. May be this will help you to solve your problem:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    if (drawerOpen) {
        dataList.remove(2);
        p1 = sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.USERS_POINTS, "");
        p2 = sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.LEVEL_ONE_POINTS,
                "");
        p3 = sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.LEVEL_TWO_POINTS,
                "");
        String pointText = " POINTS";
        dataList.add(2, new DrawerItem("MY POINTS ", p1 + pointText,
                Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
        dataList.remove(3);
        dataList.add(3, new DrawerItem("REFERRALS POINTS LV1 ", p2
                + pointText, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
        dataList.remove(4);
        dataList.add(4, new DrawerItem("REFERRALS POINTS LV2 ", p3
                + pointText, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));


        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: this one works, but it slows down the toggling of navigation drawer. It creates a lag / pause, when the ND is in the middle of toggling

Comment: if you dont have that drawerList but a menu you need to pass to the isDrawerOpen(..) the id of second childe of main  DrawerLayout xml . Like R.id.nav_view

Answer (score 2):

Calling of **notifyDatasetChanged()** still applies to ListView adapter, regardless of **ListView** parent. you have to reset the adapter using **notifyDatasetChanged()** in when your drawer is open and close and **update** the listview using **setadapter.**

Comment: please have a look on my above code and please tell me which place i need to put this.

Comment: onDrawerOpen and onDrawerClosed

Comment: in this code you want me to change 

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
        }
    };

Comment: still stuck in same page

Comment: i am very new please tell in my above code what are the changes are required?

Comment: please tell me how to do that. I have added adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); in my below code:


mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
        }
    };

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to update the Drawer Layout, update the custom adapter by calling, `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and then call `mDrawerLayout.invalidate();`

Make sure that the `getView()` method inside your adapter picks up the latest points value.

Comment: please have a look on my updated code and tell me what and where i need to change.

Comment: its comes from the server when i open drawer menu where in also displaying points is getting change but not in drawer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the drawer items when user has selected some item in the drawer. 
Then

1. you should refresh the adapter for the listview in `onItemClick`.
2. call `notifydatasetchange()` to reflect the changes.

But, if you want if user has selected some item in the list, then on closing of drawer after making selection, you want to update the list, for this case you

1. Listen for closing of drawer event -

   public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

   // refresh adapter and call notify data set change.

   }

This [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) explains the various events for drawer

Answer (score 1):

You can call the item from your navigationView object.

```
    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_item_tal).setTitle("elTitulo");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is,

In the adapter of the `listview` that you displayed in the `drawer`, within `getView()`, while creating each view you can register a listener by passing the view to update. When you get the points check whether the view is null(may be it is not in screen), and update the view if not. :)

**UPDATE**

If you want to refresh your list on `open/close` you may need something like this

[Drawer Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html)
    Which contains the following callbacks

```
onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
onDrawerStateChanged(int newState)
```

On these callbacks you call call `notifyDataSetChanged` to update listView

Comment: could please give me a sample or if i will paste my code will help me on this?

Comment: please have a look on my latest code and tell me what and where i need to change.

Comment: Which view in the layout you want to alter dynaimically ?

Comment: i did not understand what you asked?

Comment: Instead of refreshing whole view, you can update the rows in listview. It is the efficient one. So let me know the view that you need to update in each row

Comment: No only these three rows

dataList.add(new DrawerItem("MY POINTS ", p1 + pointText, Color.BLACK,
            Color.BLACK));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("REFERRALS POINTS LV1 ", p2 + pointText,
            Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("REFERRALS POINTS LV2 ", p3 + pointText,
            Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));